# Espaço em branco no final de cada índice do array?

Tags: php, array

Estou realizando uma quebra de linhas sem usar a função `wordwrap()`.

Receberei uma string com o texto, e um int com o comprimento de caracteres permitido por linhas como parâmetro. Terei que cortar essa string, depois inserí-la num vetor já cortada.

Porém quando insiro no array, eu termino com um espaço em branco para cada linha do array, por exemplo:

```
Array(0)=> 'eu irei '

Array(1)=> 'ser '
```

Quando era pra ser:

```
Array(0)=> 'eu irei'

Array(1)=> 'ser'
```

Isso gera um erro na hora de comparação com o teste. Como removo esse espaço em branco no final de cada linha?

```
class Resolution implements TextWrapInterface {

public function textWrap(string $text,int $length):array {
    //local variables
$words=explode(" ",$text); //separate the text into words
$arr=array();              //array used for return
$string=" ";
$limit=$length; //limit of characters per line
$line=0;//array line

for($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++){
    $string = $words[$i]." ";
    if((strlen($words[$i])>$length)){
        //cut the world and print the remaining letters on the next line
        $this->cutWord($arr,$words[$i],$limit,$length,$line);  
    }else
        if($limit>=strlen($string)){    
            //add the word in array line
            $arr[$line]=(array_key_exists($line,$arr))?$arr[$line].$string:$string;
            //subtract the limit with the quantity of characters
            $limit-=strlen($string);
        }else 
            if($limit<strlen($string)){

                //line++ for inserting the string on a next index
                $line++;
                $limit=$length;
                //add the word on array line
                $arr[$line]=$string;
                //subtract the limit with the quantity of characters
                $limit-=strlen($string);
            }
}

   return $arr;
   print_r($arr);

 }

 //and then I've got a cutWord function
 private function cutWord(&$array,$word,&$limit,$length,$index){

  for($i = 0; $i < strlen($word); $i++){ 

//verify if the index doesn't have any words in
if(($limit!=$length)&&($i==0)){
    $index++; // jump an array line
    $limit=$length; //limit receives starting value
}
//verify if the limit is > 0
if($limit<=0) {
    $index++;
    $limit=$length; //limit receives starting value
}
//add the letter in the array index concatenating with the previous
$array[$index]=(array_key_exists($index,$array))?$array[$index].$word[$i]:$word[$i];
$limit--;
 }
   $array[$index]=$array[$index]." ";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para remover espaços no inicio e no fim de uma string pode usar a função [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php). Se quiser remover apenas no fim tem uma variante do `trim` que pode usar e que se chama [`rtrim`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rtrim.php) (o nome vem de right trim). Estas funções devolvem a nova string ao invés de alterarem a original.

A utilização é simples como:

```
$stringSemEspacoNoFim = rtrim ($string);
```

Aplicando no seu código:

```
if($limit<strlen($string)){
    $arr[$line] = rtrim($arr[$line]); //aplicação do trim no fim de construir a linha

    //line++ for inserting the string on a next index
    $line++;
```

Comment: Implementei a rtrim no código como enviou, e ela imprimiu a string sem espaço nenhum, apenas no primeiro índice do array, por que será? O conceito está certo.

Comment: @Apprentice345 Provavelmente porque não está a ser aplicado no local certo, que não interpretei o seu código todo de alto a baixo. Experimente colocar o `rtrim` dentro do `if($limit<strlen($string)){` e antes do `$line++`, da seguinte forma: `$arr[$line] = rtrim($arr[$line]);`. Se o `rtrim` for aplicado palavra a palavra, vai lhe remover os espaços todos que não é o que quer, e provavelmente o que está a acontecer.

Comment: Deu certo, funcionou, muito obrigado!